# Is it possible to configuring Kafka SASL authentication on the osquery agent?

Tags: apache-kafka, osquery, apache-kafka-security

I'm trying setup osquery logging as a Kafka producer w/ SASL-plain authentication.
But not sure is it possible or not.

According to this page https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment/logging/#logging-as-a-kafka-producer

> There are 3 Kafka configurations are exposed as option: a comma
>   delimited list of brokers with or without the port; a default topic
>   [default value: ""], and acks...  See official documentation for more details.

**Does it mean that authentication settings not supported by osquery?**

Here is piece of config:

```
{
  "options": {
    "logger_kafka_brokers": "some.example1.com:9092,some.example2.com:9092",
    "logger_kafka_topic": "base_topic",
    "logger_kafka_compression": "gzip",
    "logger_kafka_acks": "1"
  }
```

In Kafka official documentation available 'JAAS configuration property' only: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_plain_clientconfig

```
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="alice" \
    password="alice-secret";
```

**Is there any way to use this properties for osquery?**